# Using a lambda expression in Session

Tags: java, lambda, jakarta-mail, java-8

I am writing a Javafx application in which an email is sent using JavaMail. When creating a new Session I use the syntax.

```
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, 
            //Use labmda expression?
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {

                protected javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){
                return new javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);

                }
            }
        );
```

I was wondering if a lambda expression could be used to simplify that such as

```
() -> return new java.mail.PasswordAuthentiaction(userName, password)
```

but whenever I use that it throws Incompatible types, and says that Authenticator isn't a functional interface.

Comment: You might need to wrap out the Authenticator and implement a default implementation for the methods except one. Then you will have a functional interface, which you can use for your purpose

Comment: "*but whenever I use that it throws Incompatible types, and says that Authenticator isn't a functional interface*" if `Authenticator` is not [functional interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#approach6) (note: abstract class with only one abstract method is not considered functional *interface*) then no, you can't use lambda to implement its method.

Comment: I don't believe your syntax is correct either.  You need brackets around your return statement.

Comment: In terms of syntax, one could avoid brackets by also removing `return`. But yes, it can only be assigned to a functional interface, AFAIK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't use lambda here. Lambdas can be used only as representation of implementation of functional interface (interface with only one abstract method) but `Authenticator` is not functional interface because

1. it doesn't have exactly one abstract method which lambda should implement (actually it doesn't have *any* abstract methods)
2. it is **class** (abstract, but still *class*) not **interface**.

So once again, lambdas can be used only with interfaces with one abstract method. This way lambda knows which method it implements (knows its signature so it knows number of required arguments, their type and type or expected returned value if any).
Also we don't say that lambdas can be used with any SAM (Single Abstract Method - like abstract classes) types, because it can be used only with SAM *interfaces* (functional interfaces).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the explanation for why you can't use lambdas here, note that you probably [don't even need to use an Authenticator](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes) at all.

Comment: Interesting and all, but where's the `Transport.send(message, username, password)` signature?

Comment: In the [JavaMail javadocs](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Transport.html#sendMessage-javax.mail.Message-javax.mail.Address:A-), of course.  Isn't that the first place you look for API documentation?

Comment: Gotcha! Missed the JavaMail part on this topic. I was looking for the usual J2E Transport