# Can we use the Lambda Expression for WindowListener? if yes how? if no why? Can i set the Lambda Expression for the below code snippet?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, windowlistener

```
this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdaptor(){
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we)
{
    System.exit(0);//to close the window
}
});
```

This is my request, please make the code using lambda expression.

Comment: Similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26875548/1393766

Answer (score 4):

A lambda expression can substitute a functional interface (i.e. an interface with a single non default method). Therefore WindowAdapter, which has multiple methods (`windowActivated(WindowEvent e)`, `windowClosed(WindowEvent e)`, `windowClosing(WindowEvent e)`, ...), can't be substituted by a lambda expression.

Comment: Short reference about lambdas and functional interfaces: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#approach5

Answer (score 1):

Directly you cannot use lambdas here, but if you have pretty much UI code where you have plenty of listeners, you may create a builder like this:

```
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class ListenerBuilder {
    static final Consumer<WindowEvent> nullConsumer = e -> {}; 

    private Consumer<WindowEvent> opened = nullConsumer;
    private Consumer<WindowEvent> closing = nullConsumer;
    private Consumer<WindowEvent> closed = nullConsumer;
    private Consumer<WindowEvent> iconified = nullConsumer;
    private Consumer<WindowEvent> deiconified = nullConsumer;
    private Consumer<WindowEvent> activated = nullConsumer;
    private Consumer<WindowEvent> deactivated = nullConsumer;

    public ListenerBuilder opened(Consumer<WindowEvent> opened) 
    { this.opened = opened; return this; }

    public ListenerBuilder сlosing(Consumer<WindowEvent> closing) 
    { this.closing = closing; return this; }

    public ListenerBuilder closed(Consumer<WindowEvent> closed) 
    { this.closed = closed; return this; }

    public ListenerBuilder iconified(Consumer<WindowEvent> iconified) 
    { this.iconified = iconified; return this; }

    public ListenerBuilder deiconified(Consumer<WindowEvent> deiconified) 
    { this.deiconified = deiconified; return this; }

    public ListenerBuilder activated(Consumer<WindowEvent> activated) 
    { this.activated = activated; return this; }

    public ListenerBuilder deactivated(Consumer<WindowEvent> deactivated) 
    { this.deactivated = deactivated; return this; }

    public WindowListener build() {
        return new WindowListener() {
            public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
                opened.accept(e);
            }
            public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
                iconified.accept(e);
            }
            public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
                deiconified.accept(e);
            }
            public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
                deactivated.accept(e);
            }
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                closing.accept(e);
            }
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                closed.accept(e);
            }
            public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
                activated.accept(e);
            }
        };
    }

    public void attachTo(Window w) {
        w.addWindowListener(build());
    }
}
```

After that it can be used like this:

```
this.addWindowListener(new ListenerBuilder()
    .opened(e -> log.info("Window is opened!"))
    .closed(e -> System.exit(0)).build());
```

Or like this:

```
new ListenerBuilder()
    .opened(e -> log.info("Window is opened!"))
    .closed(e -> System.exit(0)).attachTo(this);
```

Comment: The drawback of this design is that it silently overwrites a handler if a method is called more than once. Further, the generated listener references the handlers though the builder instance which makes it mutable and the entire usage of the Builder pattern pointless.

Comment: Despite the simple example implementation, the idea of using a builder here is great. Lombok can generate a builder for you. The auto-generated builder fixes all the mentioned drawbacks.